# Wild Mustang champagne cocktail

Tags: cocktails

Does anyone know of a champagne cocktail with vodka and Grand Marnier called a Wild Mustang. We used to get it is Whistler but the bar has closed and we can't find the recipe online anywhere.

Comment: All of the recipes I find for a "Wild Mustang" don't sound anything like what you're talking about. I found one reference for a "Mustang" that is just champagne with vodka... I guess adding Grand Marnier could make it "wild"... You might try the "Queen's Cousin", which is a champagne, vodka, Grand Marnier drink that also includes lime juice, bitters and triple sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking online, I found this  [menu](http://letsgofordinner.com/static/images/markets/whistler/monksgrill/menus/Summer_Dinner_Menu.pdf) from a Monk's Grill that appears to be in Vancouver. Under Champagne Cocktails it lists a Wild Mustand as having Skyy vodka and Grand Marnier. See below, copied from the menu:

> WILD MUSTANG splash of Skyy Vodka & Grand Marnier

Searching on end, however, I have not been able to find a recipe for the drink. Based on some other recipes I've found that are similar, here's a suggestion you might start with:

In a martini glass,

- Pour 1 oz. Grand Marnier
- Add a splash of your favorite vodka
- Fill the remainder of the glass with well-chilled champagne or sparkling wine
- Garnish with a slice of orange

Hopefully this will get you started and, as with all mixed drinks, you can refine to your taste.

Comment: Sounds like this was most likely a house cocktail, rather than a classic with a canonical recipe. It's possible that the head bartender took the recipe with them when their previous bar closed, and set up shop in a new location. My only suggestion for the above would be to use a champagne flute rather than a martini glass - it'll help preserve the bubbles.

Comment: 1oz Grand Marnier will overpower the taste of the champagne. I would use 1/2 oz to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Wild Mustangs are not designed to be a cocktail but a pitcher drink.

- Vodka in freezer, pitcher in freezer, flutes in freezer, Grand Marnier in freezer, Champagne in fridge  (as cold as you can get it without freezing.)

Put in the pitcher: Magnum of champagne, mickey of vodka, couple shots of Grand Marnier.

Stir with a glass rod, go.

Comment: Is this based on experience working near Whistler or somewhere else connected to the cocktail the OP remembers?

Comment: From Whistler, Banff, Jasper but had migrated to Calgary.  I have used it as the morning after for weddings, house warmings and giant wakes since the very early 80's